# Parsing XML Soap Response With Python using Element Tree

Tags: python, xml, soap, elementtree

I have a XML Soap Response in this format , Which Has following info Username: Fulname: State: State Duration:

```
<return>
        <columns>
            <values>
                <data>Username</data>
                <data>Full Name</data>
                <data>State</data>
                <data>State Duration</data>
            </values>
        </columns>
        <rows>
            <values>
                <data>user1@test.com</data>
                <data>User1</data>
                <data>Logged Out</data>
                <data>309</data>
            </values>
        </rows>
        <rows>
            <values>
                <data>user2@test.com</data>
                <data>User2</data>
                <data>Logged In</data>
                <data>165</data>
            </values>
        </rows>
        <rows>
            <values>
                <data>user3@test.com</data>
                <data>User3</data>
                <data>Logged Out</data>
                <data>109</data>
            </values>
        </rows>
   </return>
```

I want to get the total of logged in users, In this case result will be - "1"
Name of logged in users - "user2"
And sum of State Duration - 309+165+109

To start with , I am using

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
root = ElementTree.fromstring(input_data['tmp'])
tree = ElementTree.parse(input_data['tmp'])
print tree.find('.//Data').text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input_data = """<return>
        <columns>
            <values>
                <data>Username</data>
                <data>Full Name</data>
                <data>State</data>
                <data>State Duration</data>
            </values>
        </columns>
        <rows>
            <values>
                <data>user1@test.com</data>
                <data>User1</data>
                <data>Logged Out</data>
                <data>309</data>
            </values>
        </rows>
        <rows>
            <values>
                <data>user2@test.com</data>
                <data>User2</data>
                <data>Logged In</data>
                <data>165</data>
            </values>
        </rows>
        <rows>
            <values>
                <data>user3@test.com</data>
                <data>User3</data>
                <data>Logged Out</data>
                <data>109</data>
            </values>
        </rows>
   </return>"""

from xml.etree import ElementTree
root = ElementTree.fromstring(input_data)
data = [c.text for c in root.findall('.//rows/values/data')]
i = 1
for u, l in zip(data[::4], data[2::4]):
    if l == 'Logged In':
        print('"%i" Name of logged in users - "%s"' % (i, u))
        i += 1
print('Duration: %i' % sum(int(d) for d in data[3::4]))
```

Output:

```
"1" Name of logged in users - "user2@test.com"
Duration: 583
```

Comment: Worked like  a charm !! 
Thanks a lot! What do I call you? GOD ?

Comment: @richie It's better that you make effort yourself, StackOverflow isn't place for answering your homework questions.